# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'cassandra.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

I'm setting up square api, integrated it in client side and now working on server side but for that i need to manage dependencies with `composer`, while installing composer I got above error.

I was installing composer, when i run `composer install`, composer was installed but I got the PHP warning in addition i.e

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'cassandra.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I googled and tried all the solutions that have already been done, but none worked to mine. I have tried:

1. To find out cassandra at php.ini in /etc/php/7.2/cli but i did't find it.
2. To install Cassandra by using command `sudo apt-get install php-cassandra` in `/usr/lib/php/20170718`, but it still shows the same error.
3. Update and upgrade the Ubuntu, to make sure that there are no internal errors, if there was any?

I expect to install cassandra and load it dynamically.

Comment: Did you install the DataStax C/C++ driver as well? The PHP driver is a wrapper around the C API in the C/C++ driver.

Comment: I haven't installed DataStax,Before installing it What I want to know is,is this extension is pre-embaded/pre-installed while installing php or not ?( I just want to know this because ,my error was seen recently). For checking whether there is already installed or not i used  'php --re DataStax' command and got 'Exception: Extension DataStax does not exist' message in return ,is this right way to check DataStax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataStax PHP driver extension is a wrapper around the C/C++ driver and requires [installation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.3/building) of all of its dependencies:

- [C/C++ driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/latest/topics/building)

  - [libuv](http://libuv.org) 1.x
  - [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org) v1.0.x or v1.1.x (depends on how your PHP is built)
- [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org)

Since you are using the PHP driver with PHP v7.2 you will need to build the extension as their are no pre-built binaries for this version of PHP:

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
cd php-driver/ext
phpize
cd ..
mkdir build
cd build
../ext/configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Note**: The development packages of all of dependencies will be required in order to properly build the extension.

Once the driver is installed you will need to edit your `php.ini` file to enable the extension which can be located by executing `php -r "echo php_ini_loaded_file();"`:

```
; DataStax PHP Driver for Apache Cassandra
extension=cassandra.so
```

To ensure the the driver is being properly loaded via CLI you can execute the following:

```
php -m | grep cassandra
```

or

```
php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"
```

`php -m` will print out all the extension/modules that PHP was able to load whereas `php -i` will display more verbose information about your PHP installation configuration.

Comment: after ../ext/configure command i got  "configure: error: Unable to load libgmp" ,msg what's wrong here,how can i load libgmp ?

Comment: You need to install the development libraries for The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (e.g. libgmp-dev on Debian/Ubuntu and gmp-devel on CentOS/RHEL platforms).